# Mutual information I(X, Y) >= I(f(X), f(Y)) for deterministic f?

Tags: markov-process, information-theory, mutual-information

I have the intuition that applying a deterministic function to a pair random variables cannot increase their mutual information, because the function can only decrease each of their entropies.

I would like to know if this is true and prove it.

So far I've been trying to expand the mutual information definition to reach to the inequality with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct. See [this](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/zivg/ECE_5630_Lectures10.pdf) source, Property 4. It follows from the Markov chain property, i.e.
If we have a markov chain of the following form:
$$X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z$$
then, $$I(X; Z)\leq I(X;Y)$$

This can be specialized to $Z=f(Y)$. The same property can be applied for the other random variable, $X$, as well, and you get
$$I(X;Y)\geq I(f(X);g(Y))$$
in general, and letting $f=g$ yields what you ask.